# select jtable cells from particular column

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable where I need to allow selection only from ***column2***. If a user selects **row1 x *column3***, then the selection should change to **row1 x *column2***.

eg. In the table below:-

```
    co1 co2 co3 co4
ro1  a   b   c   d
ro2  e   f   g   h
ro3  i   j   k   l
ro4  m   n   o   p
```

When the user selects cell "a","b","c" or "d".... selection should change to cell "b" (***column2***)
Same with e,f,g,h -> f (***column2***)
Same with i,j,k,l -> j (***column2***)
Same with m,n,o,p -> n (***column2***)

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to handle selection change events and select particular columns:

```
final int columnIndex = 2; //index of your column
//listener that changes selection.
ListSelectionListener selectParticularColumnListener = new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        //this method should have access to your JTable
        table.setColumnSelectionInterval(columnIndex, columnIndex);
    }
};

//listen for row selection changes
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(selectParticularColumnListener);
//listen for column selection changes
table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(selectParticularColumnListener);
```